# Проверить программу по указаному пути

Tags: c#, .net

Дан путь к директории, нужно проверить соответствует ли программа которая в папке  той программе которая нужна.Например по пути лежит Фотошоп, нужно программно проверить действительно ли там Фотошоп а ни что-то другое.Какие есть способы?

Comment: можно использовать классы FileInfo/FileVersionInfo, чтобы получить информацию по данному файлу, наверно на более рассчитывать не приходится

Comment: Если у вас есть файл-образец, с которым можно сравнить - сравните побайтово. Если файл-образец хранить нет возможности - храните хеш от него и сравнивайте хеши. Если у вас образца нет и не было никогда, то никак.

Comment: _... проверить действительно ли там Фотошоп_...
Что вы имеете в виду: проверить там настоящий (лицензионный)  фотошоп или проверить на наличие файла с именем photoshop.exe?

Comment: Каждая установленная программа создаёт в реестре свои разделы и ключи (включая ассоциации типов файлов), плюс ОС создаёт связанные с программой разделы и ключи (скажем, в Uninstall). В некоторых из них содержатся путь установки и полное имя исполняемого файла. Проверяйте их. Наличие же файла в файловой системе для такого продукта ни о чём не говорит - папку с программой можно и скопировать в другое место... А вот для неинсталлируемых продуктов надёжна только проверка в файловой системе, плюс проверка реестра, если программа при работе создаёт там некие разделы/ключи с описанными выше данными.

Comment: @Akina можно пожалуйста подробнее про реестр.Как оттуда достать путь к программе

Comment: Каждая программа своё пишет. Так что для своей конкретной программы и смотри.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как Вам уже писали в комментариях:

1) Файловая система (комментарий пользователя @pasha goroshko):

класс [FileInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netcore-2.0):

это даст Вам подробную информацию о размере файла, атрибутах, директории, расширении, датах (создания, изменения) - т.е. то что Вы видите в винде через основное окошко свойств

класс [FileVersionInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo?view=netframework-4.7.2):

даст Вам знания обо всех дополнительных свойствах файла - Свойства -> Подробно

2) Реестр (комментарий пользователя @Akina):

Класс [Registry](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry?view=netframework-4.7) и класс [RegistryKey](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey?view=netframework-4.7)

Эти классы дадут возможность посмотреть конкретные параметры в реестре.

В последнем случае Вам надо знать в какую ветку и что пишет изучаемая Вами программа.

Еще как вариант (слегка фантастический): получив имя файла без расширения - сделать через какой-нибудь api запрос в интернет - и там выяснить что это.

Проверить лицензию/подлинность файла уже сложнее и потребует больших телодвижений.

Все зависит от цели Вашей программы. Уточните вопрос - может решение совершенно другое